# Adding Sound to splash screen in iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio

I would like to add some background music to the splash screen in the iPhone. I have already increased the splash screen time by few seconds.. And the music isn't long... But I am not sure how to do it? Need some guidance...

Comment: mp3 or wav? I think looping should work, when the splash is finished stop the music also

Comment: mp3.. wanted to add music to spice it up...

Comment: Extending the Default.png time is against Apple's Human Interface Guidelines and is grounds for denial. Just a warning.

Comment: Hey what happened to my answer ? Didn't it helped ?

Comment: Thax buddy. My code works even iPhone volume is muted i.e. it will play the sound compare to accepted solution. And is generic too so I was bit disappointed. Anyway thats okay. Thax once again for +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about putting it in you `application didFinishLaunching` but be sure to instantiate it in you .h and .m.

Something like this should do your problem:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/YOURMUSICNAME.mp3"];
    NSLog(@"Path to play: %@", resourcePath);
    NSError* err;

    //Initialize our player pointing to the path to our resource
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                 [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];

    if( err ){
        //bail!
        NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        //set our delegate and begin playback
        player.delegate = self;
        [player play];
        player.numberOfLoops = -1;
        player.currentTime = 0;
        player.volume = 1.0;
    }
}
```

Then if you want to stop it:

```
[player stop];
```

or pause it :

```
[player pause];
```

and also import it in your header file:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

and add this to your header the **bold** part:

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <**AVAudioPlayerDelegate**>

Comment: am i right to say it can be used for anywhere in the app right? i mean like the main menu... will it differ?

Comment: YUP. this can be use anywhere ;)

Comment: Initialize it in your header the synthesize in .m

Comment: @synthesize player? something like this?

Comment: Yup. Then in header avplayer* player. The set its property too

Comment: Property delegate not found on object of AVPlayer type?

Comment: yup my bad, it is` AVAudioPlayer *player;`, do you still have problems?

Comment: player.delegate = self. This line is giving me error..passing appdelegate const_strong to parameter of incompatible type idA AVAudioPlayerDelegate

Answer (score 5):

Use following function for playing sound file.

```
-(void)playSoundFromFileName:(NSString*)pstrFileName ofType:(NSString*)pstrFileType
{   
    SystemSoundID bell;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:pstrFileName ofType:pstrFileType]], &bell);  
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (bell);    
}
```

Call this function in application delegate didfinishlaunchingwithoptions method...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
     ...
     [self playSoundFromFileName:@"yourfile" ofType:@"extension"];

}
```

Comment: i tried your code and it is giving me errors: use of undeclared identifier called SystemSoundID.. must i include something? did i forget something? please help...

Comment: You need to add #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h> statement and add AudioToolbox Framework to your project.

Answer (score 5):

my personal taste: don't bother your users, and get out of the splash as fast as you can

Comment: It was never designed to be a "Splash Screen". The whole idea was that it would be a static image that showed your UI with no data. Then this would be displayed to give the user the idea that your app has launched immediately and then you populated the real UI with the data which was then ready when the image was removed. That's what Apple's guidelines stated, but then it seems people started to abuse it and it was allowed through. Now it seems people want to abuse it even more!

Comment: I know, but everybody calls it "splash screen" instead of Launch Image